# Effect of simultaneous Physical Stress

Tags: stress, cortex-plus, marvel-heroic-roleplaying

Here is the situation that happened in today's game:

Johnny Storm (Human Torch) as a NPC has d12 of Physical Stress, and has activated his Nova Flame SFX on his previous action.

He is attacked by a PC. He exploits his own stress on his reaction, but fails it by 15. His highest rolling dice on the reaction is a d12.

This means that simultaneously:

1. His Physical Stress is step-up to d12+1, because he used it in his roll.
2. He receives d12 Physical Stress from his Nova Flame.
3. He receives d12+3 Physical Stress from the PC's attack.

Again, this all happens at the same time. We never had this kind of situation before, and couldn't find if the rules covered it.

How would that work?

- They are all applied one after the other. He takes d12+1 Stress and Trauma d6, then d12+3 Trauma, and is actually dead (not impossible, and I am not against it).
- Only the biggest effect of the three is applied. He takes d12+3 Stress and Trauma d6.
- Something else?

---

*Disclaimer: I am looking for an answer as official as possible. I know it is "narrative first" and I could declare him dead or not. I know I could transfer the Stress to mental or emotional just in case. And I know I could ask the player if he wants to not stress him out.*

Comment: I hope the disclaimer doesn't offend anyone, I prefer being very clear rather than having an answer that doesn't answer the question I *wanted* to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Well, I have an answer of sorts, as Cam Banks answered to my question [somewhere else](http://www.margaretweis.com/mwp_forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=2097). Since [Cam has an account here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/5700/cam-banks), I will remove this answer if he ever passes by. Here is his answer:*

> There is actually an order in play here.
>
> Firstly, he exploits his own stress, including it in his reaction.
>   After rolling the dice for his reaction, his stress is stepped up past
>   d12, effectively stressing him out and giving him d6 trauma. This
>   happens first because it was initiated first (including it in the dice
>   pool happens before the reaction is resolved). You continue to resolve
>   the reaction since that's assumed to have happened, of course, but
>   what happens next is that his Nova Flame SFX kicks in, inflicting d12
>   stress, which translates directly into trauma, and as d12 trauma is
>   more than d6 trauma, you replace the d6 trauma with d12. This happens
>   next because it's a result of his SFX.
>
> Then of course Johnny takes even more stress because he fails his
>   reaction by 15, so Johnny's trauma goes past d12. He's dead, in a
>   vegetative state, or otherwise out of the story. He doesn't need to
>   die; he could be in a coma. But he's not getting up for the rest of
>   whatever Event he's in.
>
> Cheers, Cam